# Is there a way to do inspect element for android apps

Tags: android, android-studio

Like chrome developer tools, is their something built for android apps, something which you can find the media, images present in a particular view. With Android System Monitor, you can only debug the apps you made, whereas what I want to do is for apps running on my phone currently.

P.S I don't want to inspect webpages appearing on my phone,rather I want to inspect the applications running on my phone currently.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Any app with `android:debuggable = false` cannot be debugged, and most release builds will have the attribute set to false. There are of course exceptions, but there aren't many.

See also [this link](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/android/DRD10-X.+Do+not+release+apps+that+are+debuggable) on why it's a bad idea having a debuggable app in production

Comment: What about an app, (like ankidroid) that is debuggable, but the its debug tool only works on a single screen ("note" view)?