# Are there any tools for inspecting CSS values in a mobile app? I need it specifically for font size, color, padding

Tags: css, user-interface, user-experience, web-inspector

So our design team needs a stand alone tool. This is for a mobile app.
This tool should be able to get CSS values of individual elements like font color, font size, padding, and other UX values.

Are there any easy to setup tools which the team can use to achieve this?

I tried using browserstack and it's appium inspector. But it does not show CSS values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlIpH.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several such tools available to get CSS values of individual elements for a mobile app like Browser Developer Tools, Zeplin, Avocode, Figma, etc.

You can Google more about such tools.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but I need to inspect elements on the mobile app. We do not have design files on Figma.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to other answers on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/49338868/19448419